# Android SharedPreferences Store Data

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am using SharedPreferences for storing some user data it works correctly when I store data once but when I want to test on another Android OS version it does not work and I have to store data once again.
Thanks in advance
This is my code:

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

//storing data
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

editor.putString("exchange_rate", rate);
editor.putString("my_token", token);
editor.putString("my_url", url_value);
editor.commit();

//getting data from SharedPreference
usd_rate.setText(sharedpreferences.getString("exchange_rate",null));
token_key.setText(sharedpreferences.getString("my_token",null));
url.setText(sharedpreferences.getString("my_url",null));
```

Comment: Shared Preference will be in first device only. it will not there in second device.

Comment: You need to store sharedPreferences once again

Comment: What is the best way for this issue SID?

Comment: use webservice for fulfill your pirpose. store data on webserver/ php/ db. and retrive from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Gul SharedPreferences are used to store data on a device **locally** not for **globally**.

If you want to store your data so that you can access it at any device store your data on webserver using any database like MySql etc.

you can also use cloud.